# How to set timeout in apache cxf dynamic client

Tags: cxf

I'm using the [Apache CXF DynamicClientFactory](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html) to dynamically request web services. How can I set a timeout there? I can only find examples with static generated java stubs, but no example for the dynamic approach... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try taking a look [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html).

If you scroll down a bit, you will see how to set the timeout using an integer.

Comment: Hi, do you know in which package the mentioned Option is located? I want to use the java code snippet from http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#timeout_config

Comment: Dear, your answer is completely wrong since it's pointing a Axis2 link, not a CXF one. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) yourStub.get...Port();    
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(bp);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Found this [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) and something similar [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17266_01/English/Technical_Documentation/Web_Services/ProgrammersGuide/helpmain.htm?toc.htm?34314.htm).